# Hidden Dictionaries Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a simple Text Based File System. Anyhow I am having trouble when printing out all three parts to my File System. In the File System there are three parts, the Name, Date, and Text. The Name is the file's name, the Date is the date the file was written on, and the Text is the file's contents. Now when I am appending the Name, Date, and Text to the files dictionary I can not get the Text to print out. Below is the code I am using to append the three variables to the dictionary.

```
files[filename] = {filedate:filetext}
```

Then I am using the following code to print out each of the values. (Only the Name and Date will print out)

```
    for filename in files:
        print "--------------------------------------------"
        print "File Name: " + str(filename)
        for filedate in files[filename]:
            print "File Date: " + str(filedate)
            for filetext in files.values():
                print "File Contents: " + str(filetext)
```

I am not sure why it won't work correctly. Below is my full code so far.

```
import datetime
import time

files = {}
# g = open('files.txt', 'r')
# g.read(str(files))
# g.close()

def startup():
    print "\n          -------------------          "
    print "          FILE SYSTEM MANAGER          "
    print "          -------------------          "
    print "\n What would you like to do with your files?"
    print "   To make a new file type in: NEW"
    print "   To edit a current file type in: EDIT"
    print "   Tp delete a current file type in: DELETE"
    print "   To view all current files type in: ALL"
    print "   To search a specific file type in: SEARCH"
    chooser = raw_input("\n Please enter NEW, EDIT, DELETE, ALL, or SEARCH: ")
    if chooser.lower() == "new":
        newfile()
    elif chooser.lower() == "edit":
        editfiles()
    elif chooser.lower() == "delete":
        deletefiles()
    elif chooser.lower() == "all":
        allfiles()
    elif chooser.lower() == "search":
        searchfiles()
    else:
        startup()

#-- New File -------------------------------
def newfile():
    filename = ""
    filetext = ""
    while filename == "":
        print "--------------------------------------------"
        filename = raw_input("\n Please input your new files name: ")
    while filetext == "":
        filetext = raw_input("\n Please input the text for your new file: ")
    filedate = datetime.date.today()
    files[filename] = {filedate:filetext}
    # f = open ('files.txt', 'w')
    # f.write(str(files))
    # f.close()
    print "\n File Added"
    print "\n--------------------------------------------"
    print "\n          -------------------          "
    print "          FILE SYSTEM MANAGER          "
    print "          -------------------          "
    print "\n What would you like to do with your files?"
    print "   To make a new file type in: NEW"
    print "   To edit a current file type in: EDIT"
    print "   Tp delete a current file type in: DELETE"
    print "   To view all current files type in: ALL"
    print "   To search a specific file type in: SEARCH"
    chooser = raw_input("\n Please enter NEW, EDIT, DELETE, ALL, or SEARCH: ")
    if chooser.lower() == "new":
        newfile()
    elif chooser.lower() == "edit":
        editfiles()
    elif chooser.lower() == "delete":
        deletefiles()
    elif chooser.lower() == "all":
        allfiles()
    elif chooser.lower() == "search":
        searchfiles()
    else:
        startup()

def editfiles():
    pass
def deletefiles():
    pass
def allfiles():
    for filename in files:
        print "--------------------------------------------"
        print "File Name: " + str(filename)
        for filedate in files[filename]:
            print "File Date: " + str(filedate)
            for filetext in files.values():
                print "File Contents: " + str(filetext)
def searchfiles():
    pass

startup()
```

P.S. If you're feeling extra nice, I am trying to get the file writing to work correctly. The parts where I have tried to write it to a file are commented out. I am not exactly sure how to write to a file, but I gave it a shot. I am writing to the files.txt file, and I want it to save the file dictionary, and open it every time the program is closed.

Comment: Shouldn't that just be `print "File Contents: " + str(filetext[filename][filedate])`? There are neater ways of dealing with dictionaries, though; see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Answer (score 1):

Besides that the structure you use is VERY weird, you should replace

```
for filetext in files.values():
```

with

```
for filetext in files[filename].values():
```

I would rather use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) to represent file record though.

Comment: The author may want to track text by date making a namedtuple a poor choice.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that `files.values()` enumerates the outer dict values (where you were placing dicts representing individual files), not the text for a given file. I am perplexed because it should have printed the entire dict - I can't explain why it didn't print anything. Nominally, you could fix it with `for filetext in files[filename].values()`, but you can also get key, value in one fell swoop and reduce the number of lookups:

```
for filename, content in files.iteritems():
    print "--------------------------------------------"
    print "File Name: " + str(filename)
    for filedate, text in content.iteritems():
        print "File Date: " + str(filedate)
        print "File Contents: " + str(filetext)
```